# What wattage of LED full spectrum grow light is best for ferns?

Tags: light

What wattage of LED grow light is best for ferns?

Comment: "fern" is very generic: there are fern that growth in full light, and some in full shadow. You may be more specific. (with very shadow fern, just a north window is enough).